# Android DrawerLayout Click Event -- How to change View

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer, selecteditem

I just started an android app that using Drawer Layout. I tried many tutorials to change the layout by clicking the leftbar items.

Here is my code.

```
public class IndexPageActivity extends ActionBarActivity
    implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_index_page);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft= fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1));
    ft.commit();





 }

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = "Inbox";

            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = "Completed Task";
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = "Settings";
            break;
        case 4:
            mTitle = "Change Password";
            break;
        case 5:
            mTitle = "Logout";
            break;
    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.actionbar_background));
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.index_page, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_index_page, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((IndexPageActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}
```

}

And my XML Page is :

```
  <!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.exactsystm.exactsystem.IndexPageActivity">

<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


<!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
     android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
<!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. -->
<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:name="com.example.exactsystm.exactsystem.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" android:textColor="#ff00" />


 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is code is generated by Android studio by default when I create a new Navigation Drawer Activity.

This working finely such as the swiping. but when I select a tab of Navigation It does not going to any sections.

How can i solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

You should just put a switch statement into the onNavigationDrawerItemSelected method:

```
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch(position) {
        default:
        case 0:
            fragment = new MyFragment1();
            break;
       case 1:
            fragment = new MyFragment2();
            break;
    }
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
        .commit();
}
```